# Will assigning nil to a retained property release the object associated to it?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsstring

when not under ARC, for the following code,

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *s;
```

.m

```
NSString *m = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hellow, World"];
s = [m retain];

// later on
s = nil; <-- will this release the ref count on the string and hence get the string released?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When used like this (i. e. by accessing the instance variable directly), then no, it won't. However, if you use the property's accessor method (`[self setS:nil];` or `self.s = nil;`), then yes, it will.

Also note that releasing an object and freeing its memory are two completely different things. An object is deallocated only when it has no more strong references - i. e. you have the last reference to it and then you release it. If you release it but it has other references (by having been retained previously), then it won't be deallocated yet, only its reference count will be decremented by one.

Furthermore, if you have a retained property, such the one in your example, you must not do 1. access the underlying instance variable directly, 2. do stuff like

```
NSString *m = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hellow, World"];
s = [m retain];
```

Why? Because the first line is simply unnecessary - really, why `- [NSString stringWithString:]`? You're creating a constant string, then create an exact copy of it - it's just superfluous. If Cocoa's designers were noobs, this line would also waste memory - two exact copies of the same immutable string. Fortunately, whoever implemented NSString was prepared for this situation and made this method check its argument for being a constant and returning it without doing anything if it is - so you get back the same pointer, but with a few extra calls to `objc_msgSend` - that's not something you want.

The second line is also wrong - again, you don't use the backing ivar as-is. Also, the property is declared `retain` for a reason - if you set an object to your property, that object will be retained by the setter method - no need to manually retain it.

All in all, you'd better write

```
self.s = @"Hello World";

// ...

self.s = nil;
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing this operation will be like this.

```
self.s = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hellow, World"]; // this will ensure that string is retained 

// later on
self.s = nil; // this will ensure that retain count is reduced.
```

Deallocation of NSString will depend upon iOS AutoreleasePool, since you are releasing the retain count, next time when GC runs it will check the total retain count of that string and if it is not used anywhere else then it will delete that object.

Answer (score 1):

All `retain` calls should be paired with a matching `release`. By assigning to `nil` you're abandoning your retained object.

Comment: what means abandoning the object? not releasing it?

Comment: @tom no, you're losing the pointer to it thus you're leaking memory.

Comment: It's important to be responsible for all objects you `retain` until they are released, and as @H2CO3 says, abandoning it is a form of leak.

Answer (score 1):

if **obj** is a property, then

```
self.obj = nil;
```

will in a fact release it for you.

But if not property or member or local variable

```
 obj = nil;
```

then u will have to manage for release

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes, assuming you use the property and don't modify the instance variable directly. The same is true if the property were `strong` instead of `retain` under ARC as well. Basically, your synthesized property will look like this:

```
- (void)setPropertyName:(NSString *)value {
  [value retain];
  [_propertyName release];
  _propertyName = value;
}
```

So, if you assign it a new value, the new value will be retained and the old value will be released. If the new and old values are the same, it will mostly have no effect.

*Note:* Bear in mind that in your example code, you are retaining the object after allocating it, so you now have ownership of the object if you go by [Cocoa memory management policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). As such, once you've set the property, you'll need to either `release` or `autorelease` the object to avoid a leak (because by using the property, the object will be retained by it as well).